# Apache2 - Stop IP redirecting to domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, web-server, configuration, apache2

After setting up SSL and using configuration found on the internet with some modification, I'm not able to access my website using ip address it is always redirecting to my https://example.com.

Here are my configuration:

`default-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
Redirect "http://100.100.100.100/" "https://100.100.100.100/"
Redirect "http://example.com" "https://example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin mail@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    ##SSL Configs here
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

`000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com 
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSLEngine on
##SSL Certificates

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

What i want is that when i use http://example.com i need to redirect it to https://example.com and when i use http://100.100.100.100 i need to redirect to https://100.100.100.100. Help me fix this issue.

Comment: You need to make a separate virtual host for both your IP address and domain name.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen do i need to do the same in both files. Can you post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way here is to create a new file for both http and https versions of IP address and DNS name virtual hosts, and configure each separately.